# RNFetchBlob requires main queue setup

Tags: react-native

When using RNFetchBlob with React Native I get a yellow warning screen that says:

> Module RNFetchBlob requires main queue setup since it overrides
>   `constantsToExport` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In
>   a future release React Native will default to initializing all native
>   modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.

I am using react-native 0.56.0 and react-native-fetch-blob: 0.10.8. This worked previously with react-native 0.54.2.

What exactly is this error telling me? What exactly is main queue setup? What should I do to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Related but not completely answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50929930/2315280

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It turns out that `react-native-fetch-blob` is no longer supported and I needed to use `rn-fetch-blob` instead. To fix this I had to do the following:

1. react-native unlink react-native-fetch-blob
2. npm uninstall --save react-native-fetch-blob
3. npm install --save rn-fetch-blob
4. react-native link

I then had to change all lines that used:

`import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';`

to:

`import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';`

Everything is now working the way that it should.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. For iOS please not that you have to run pod install in the iOS folder for it to work.

Comment: rn-fetch-blob is also no longer maintained, use react-native-blob-util instead

Answer (score 2):

If you are using react native `0.63.3`, after replacing `react-native-fetch-blob` with `rn-fetch-blob` there is no `link` command, so don't forget to execute `pod install` in `ios` directory.

Comment: This should be the updated answer for modern RN.